# Windows 7 Animation mouse drag event

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, shell, windows-7

Is there a way to have custom animation replace the defauly windows animation when you drag a window to the edge of the screen?

Answer (score 1):

You are referring to the preview animation? I do not believe so. If there is an option, it's to stop windows from even thinking you support that operation, and then trying to implement your own. I could recommend not trying to defeat the operating system here.